# Tag Wiki containing copy/pasted text from CC project?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

There was a spurious edit to the [libcurl](/questions/tagged/libcurl) tag that I declined, but also noticed that the original [libcurl](/questions/tagged/libcurl) wiki was copy/pasted verbatim from the [libcurl website](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).  This is a [free open-source](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/copyright.html) project, but the website itself doesnt' appear to be (based on the [website info](http://curl.haxx.se/about.html) page).

In this case, is this considered an appropriate use of information (since it is after all a open-source project, and the text from the main page of the website undoubtedly is not only an excellent description but is useful for the curl group as well)?  Or is this something that isn't technically appropriate and should be rewritten (not by me, as I have no clue what it *should* say).

Comment: I'm also amused by the fact that the tag excerpt was approved, but the wiki edit was declined.  Both were highly spurious (and probably net harmful, but not enough to flag I don't think) by someone who seems to be going through making spurious tag wiki edits.  Sigh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tag wikis really shouldn't contain copy/pasted content from any source, no matter what the license.  Instead the page should be linked to, along with a short description of what's behind the link.

Comment: Thanks, Bill.  Hopefully someone with libcurl knowledge will see this and edit the wiki to a better version.  If nobody does in the next day or so I might go ahead and give it a try (though I've never used libcurl and wouldn't necessarily do a good job).

Comment: @Joe I was thinking exactly the same thing. :)

Comment: Actually I might just put a bounty on it in 2 days, that might be the most effective solution.  This isn't getting many views, but that would undoubtedly solve the issue :)